# Installing triton in windows

Tags: python, windows, huggingface, triton

I am running the following on command line in windows:

```
 autotrain dreambooth --model stabilityai/stable-diffusion-xl-base-1.0 --image-path ./Anas --prompt 'a photo of arzk man' --resolution 1024 --batch-size 1 --num-steps 500 --fp16 --gradient-accumulation 4 --lr 1e-4 --project-name thesis
```

and I got the following error message

```
RuntimeError: Failed to import diffusers.pipelines.stable_diffusion_xl.pipeline_stable_diffusion_xl because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
Failed to import diffusers.models.autoencoder_kl because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
module 'triton' has no attribute '__version__
```

I tried to pip install triton but I am getting the following error message

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement triton (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for triton
```

I read in triton's [github](https://github.com/openai/triton?tab=readme-ov-file#compatibility) that it is only compatible with Linux.

I don't know how to use Linux. would i need to create a virtual environment there and install python and... that would be crazy to move everything there (probably it is not I just dont know what to do in linux).

any recommendation to what I could do ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [GitHub repo for Triton](https://github.com/openai/triton), Triton is compatible with Linux. There's no support for Windows.

A possible workaround to this would be to install [The Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) and then install the latest stable release of Triton in that environment.

Comment: thanks.... that is also what I got to. I did run 'wsl --install' ... 
but I am unfamiliar with what I exactly did by installing wsl.. and what would be the next steps--- can you explain this briefly? linux and wsl are mystery to me

Comment: WSL is basically Windows Subsystem for Linux meaning you get to have Linux environment on your Windows machine. Did you read the link I included?